# pythreejs (Python/JavaScript): How to save rendered image data?

Tags: javascript, python, three.js, render, jupyter-notebook

**Background**: I have a good understanding of `pythreejs`, and can obtain an interactive rendered object in jupyter ipython notebook that I am looking for.

**Problem**: I would like to capture the data that appears in the window as some sort of data stream like an image object. For example, I would like to send this image object to saving as a PNG, or sending it downstream somewhere for later displaying somewhere else. All I need is this PNG-like information, not the full rendered object.

Concretely, what is the best way to accomplish this image data grab in `pythreejs`? This appears as an [issue on pythreejs's Github page](https://github.com/jovyan/pythreejs/issues/22), and is not currently resolved natively in `pythreejs`. I am wondering if there is a workaround; For [example](https://github.com/jovyan/pythreejs/blob/master/examples/Examples.ipynb), we know that the `Renderer` object is some `three.js` implementation under-the-hood, and contains the image data that appears in my jupyter window. How can one capture this data as a picture or screenshot, for later displaying?

**Disclaimer**: Apologies if my explanation is not clear: I am relatively new to WebGL-type stuff, and do not know how to express myself technically with appropriate lexicon. Please ask clarifying questions, and I will try to shed more light on my problem.